# TypeScript: How do I properly type this `groupBy` function

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have the following array of objects and we want to group them by property (here color)

Here is how I wrote it in JS

```js
const users = [
  { name: 'Jim', color: 'blue' },
  { name: 'Sam', color: 'blue' },
  { name: 'Eddie', color: 'green' },
]

function groupBy(array, property) {
  return array.reduce((accu, curr) => {
    const value = curr[property]
    if (accu[value]) {
      accu[value].push(curr)
    } else {
      accu[value] = [curr]
    }
    return accu
  }, {})
}
const usersByColor = groupBy(users, 'color') // TODO: implement groupBy
```

And I am trying to write it in TypeScript

```
type GroupedArray<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in T[K]]: T[] // here it errors on `Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.`
}

function groupBy<T, K extends keyof T>(array: T[], prop: K) {
  return array.reduce((accu, curr) => {
    const value = curr[prop]
    if (accu[value]) {
      accu[value].push(curr)
    } else {
      accu[value] = [curr]
    }
    return accu
  }, {} as GroupedArray<T, K>)
}

const users = [
  { name: 'Jim', color: 'blue' },
  { name: 'Sam', color: 'blue' },
  { name: 'Eddie', color: 'green' },
]

const usersByColor = groupBy(users, 'color')
```

I got an type error for on

```
type GroupedArray<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in T[K]]: T[]
}
```

for `Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.`  I wonder what is the right way to type it?

or is there a better way to write such a function in TypeScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should give your params a limit type

```
type GroupedArray<T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in T[K]]: T[]
}

function groupBy<T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>, K extends keyof T>(array: T[], prop: K) {
  return array.reduce((accu, curr) => {
    const value = curr[prop]
    if (accu[value]) {
      accu[value].push(curr)
    } else {
      accu[value] = [curr]
    }
    return accu
  }, {} as GroupedArray<T, K>)
}

const users = [
  { name: 'Jim', color: 'blue' },
  { name: 'Sam', color: 'blue' },
  { name: 'Eddie', color: 'green' },
]

const usersByColor = groupBy(users, 'color')
```

Comment: didn't even know PropertyKey exists... thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Force the values of `T` to be `string | number | symbol`:

```
type GroupedArray<T extends Record<any, string | number | symbol>, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in T[K]]: T[]
}
```